# Multiple relationships with one table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two POCOs that I am trying to have utilize the same data type - a list of type `Contact`. However, when I try and do that, I get the following error message:

> Cannot create a relationship between 'NewMatterRequest.PartiesForConflict' and 'Contact.Request' because a relationship already exists between 'DatabaseUpdateRequest.PartiesForConflict' and 'Contact.Request'. Navigations can only participate in a single relationship. If you want to override an existing relationship call 'Ignore' on the navigation 'Contact.Request' first in 'OnModelCreating'.

This is the code I have so far:

```
[PrimaryKey(nameof(Id))]
[NotMapped]
public abstract class RequestItem
{
    [StringLength(40)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Status { get; set; } = "Pending";
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string? ClientNumber { get; set; }
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string? MatterNumber { get; set; }
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string? ClientName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string? MatterName {  get; set; }
}

[PrimaryKey(nameof(Id))]
public class NewMatterRequest : RequestItem
{
     [StringLength(150)]
     public string MatterDescription { get; set; } = string.Empty;

     public List<Contact> PartiesForConflict { get; set; } = new List<Contact>(); 
}

[PrimaryKey(nameof(Id))]
public class DatabaseUpdateRequest : RequestItem
{
    public bool AddContacts { get; set; } = false;

    public List<Contact> PartiesForConflict { get; set; } = new List<Contact>();
}

[PrimaryKey(nameof(Id))]
public class Contact
{
    [StringLength(40)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    
    public string Honarary { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    //Relationship
    public RequestItem Request { get; set; }
    [StringLength(40)]
    public string RequestId { get; set;} = string.Empty;
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // ....
    modelBuilder.Entity<DatabaseUpdateRequest>().HasMany(c => c.PartiesForConflict).WithOne(o => (DatabaseUpdateRequest)o.Request).HasForeignKey(k => k.RequestId).HasPrincipalKey(o => o.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<NewMatterRequest>().HasMany(c => c.PartiesForConflict).WithOne(o => (NewMatterRequest)o.Request).HasForeignKey(k => k.RequestId).HasPrincipalKey(o => o.Id);
}
```

Do I have my `modelbuilder` calls above wrong? I cannot seem to find the right place to place the `Ignore()` call the error message suggests, and my fear is that doing so wouldn't really achieve what I'm looking for anyhow.

Is there a better way to handle this? I'm trying to prevent creating duplicate classes `NewMatterRequestContact` / `DatabaseUpdateRequestContact` to get around this issue.

I'm utilizing GUID so, theoretically, I feel storing that value in `Contact`'s `RequestId` field should have no duplicates, even if that one table would be shared between both of the two types.

Any help/guidance here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are `NewMatterRequest` /  `DatabaseUpdateRequest` mapped to tables? If a TPH just move `PartiesForConflict` to the base type. If they are separate tables, then `Contact` would need two foreign keys and two navigation properties.... Or `Contact` would need to be a TPH.

Comment: Sorry - I should have included that: `modelBuilder.Entity<DatabaseUpdateRequest>().ToTable("DbUpdRequests");` and `modelBuilder.Entity<NewMatterRequest>().ToTable("NmRequests");` respectively. Thank you for your response and pointing me in a direction. I am going to do some digging on TPH and setting up two navigation properties

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Jeremy for pointing me in the right direction. I just needed to modify my modelbuilder logic:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
.HasOne<NewMatterRequest>(c => (NewMatterRequest)c.Request)
.WithMany(c => c.PartiesForConflict)
.HasForeignKey(c => c.RequestId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
.HasOne<DatabaseUpdateRequest>(c => (DatabaseUpdateRequest)c.Request)
.WithMany(c => c.PartiesForConflict)
.HasForeignKey(c => c.RequestId);
```

And that worked. The cast only being required because the two request types inherit from RequestItem.